# return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

Tags: python

I am reading a songs file in csv format and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
import csv
import os
import random

file = open("songs.csv", "rU")
reader = csv.reader(file)

for song in reader:
    print(song[0], song[1], song[2])

file.close()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kuku/Desktop/hey/mine/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    for song in reader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 414: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please edit your post so we can clearly see what part is the code.

Comment: I'd recommend you to open the file using 'with' syntax so file will be automatically closed after with block, there are examples at csv module documentation where they have examples how to use specific encoders: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for song in [unicode(song, 'utf-8') for song in reader]:
    print(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this bit of your code:

```
for song in reader:
    print( song[0], song[1],song[2])
```

you are printing elements 0, 1 and 2 of the lines in `reader` during each iteration of the loop. This will cause a (different) error if there are fewer than 3 elements in total.

If you don't know that there will be at least 3 elements in each line, you could include the code in a `try`, `except` block:

```
with open("songs.csv", "r") as f:
    song_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for song_line in song_reader:
        lyric = song_line
        try:
            print(lyric[0], lyric[1], lyric[2])
        except:
            pass # ...or preferably do something better
```

It's worth noting that in most cases it is preferable to open a file within a `with` block, as shown above. This negates the need for `file.close()`.

Comment: I still get the same error after trying all your code. is there a way to do it without a for loop

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting an error -- I can't replicate that.

You can read all lines using `readlines()` (without a `for` loop), i.e. `lyrics = f.readlines()`

Comment: Thank you the song,csv file was corrupt thats why i was getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in utf-8 encoding.

```
file = open("songs.csv", "rU", encoding="utf-8")
```